# Save images and videos from C++/NDK app to Android 11 gallery/DCIM folder

Tags: android, android-ndk, scoped-storage

I have a NDK app (C++) which generates large numbers of image and (possible big) video files.
Until Android Q the app created a sub-directory in the DCIM folder where it directly saved the files and used a media scanner for adding the files to the Android gallery.

With Android 11 files are written to the local directory (/emulated/0/Android/com.myname/files) for now.
How can I either move or directly save the files to the DCIM folder with Android 11 and C++/NDK?

Regards,

Comment: You can still create your own folder in DCIM and write your image files there. Same code.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work but is this in accordance with the scoped access system, or is it just accidentally working?

Comment: If you read the documents then it looks as if this should not be possible anymore. But my experience is that it works. So i will use it until Android 12 API 31 comes and then we live again..